# my buffered.readline got a values to null, need help to understand why?

Tags: java, server, client, bufferedreader, readline

thank you for helping me
I m a begginer in java and i really need some help to fix a bug from my api client connect .
I want to made an api who connect to a server , can send some request with a textfield and jButton, and print the answer from the server in a textArea .
Here everithing is working, exept the buffered.readLine , that make my api crash .Apparently, my buffer got a byte value, but at the moment i do buffered.readline, that make her values goes to null and make all the code crash .
Can somebody help me ?
Sry for my mistakes in english.

public class Serveur_client extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4959710096704722844L;
private static Serveur_client m_serveurClient = null;
private JTextField m_txtFldToMachine;
private JTextArea txtAreaFromMachine;
private static BufferedWriter m_dataToServer = null;
private static BufferedReader m_dataFromServer = null;
private static Socket socketOfClient = null;



public Serveur_client() {
    initPanel();
}

/**
 * Construct the Panel
 */
private void initPanel() {

    // Creation de l'IHM

    txtAreaFromMachine = new JTextArea("Ready to s command", 15, 38);
    txtAreaFromMachine.setEditable(false);

    m_txtFldToMachine = new JTextField(20);

    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Envoi de la commande");

    sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            m_serveurClient.sendData();
           
        }
    });

    this.add(txtAreaFromMachine);
    this.add(m_txtFldToMachine);
    this.add(sendButton);
}

private static final String SEND_COMMAND = "SEND";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    m_serveurClient = new Serveur_client();
    // Server Host

    String serverHost = args != null && args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "localhost";
    String portString = args != null && args.length > 1 ? args[1] : "9999";
    int port = 9999;
    try {
        port = Integer.parseInt(portString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        port = 9999;
    }

    String ipProp = System.getProperty("ipadresse");
    String portProp = System.getProperty("port");

    System.out.println("ipProp " + ipProp);
    System.out.println("portProp " + portProp);

    System.out.println("serverHost " + serverHost);
    System.out.println("port " + port);

    
   

    try {

        // Send a request to connect to the server is listening on machine serverHost and port.
        socketOfClient = new Socket(serverHost, port);

        // Create output stream at the client (to send data to the server)
        m_dataToServer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketOfClient.getOutputStream()));

        // Input stream at Client (Receive data from the server).
        m_dataFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketOfClient.getInputStream()));

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Erreur de connexion a l'adresse" + serverHost);
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOExeption");
        return;
    }

    // Creation de l'IHM
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test IHM");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, m_serveurClient);
    frame.setSize(400, 350);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    
}

/**
 * This method send data to serveur
 */
private void sendData() {
    String command = m_txtFldToMachine.getText();
    System.out.println("message envoyé: " + command);
    // TODO
    txtAreaFromMachine.append("\n");
    txtAreaFromMachine.append("command receive: " + command);

    try {
        m_dataToServer.write(command);
        m_dataToServer.newLine();
        m_dataToServer.flush();
        receiveData();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void receiveData() {
    try {
        // Read data sent from the server.
        // By reading the input stream of the Client Socket.
        String responseLine;

        while ((responseLine = m_dataFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("test");
            System.out.println(responseLine);
            System.out.println("Server: " + responseLine);
            if (responseLine.indexOf("OK") != -1) {
                break;
            }
        }

        m_dataToServer.close();
        m_dataFromServer.close();
        socketOfClient.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Impossible de se connecter a un hote inconnu " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
    }
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
    switch (actionCommand) {
        case SEND_COMMAND:
            m_serveurClient.sendData();
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: How does it "crash"?    Does it throw an exception?  Show us the stacktrace.

Comment: what exactly is the error? are you getting null while doing readLine() on m_dataFromServer?

Comment: the stackTrace is the problem too, i get 0 exeption, my api bug like button is unusable, and cant close the api ,when i run the code in debug run in eclypse , it send me to BufferedReader.class in the :                                        public String readLine() throws IOException {
        return readLine(false);
    }

Comment: i think the bug is because at the moment i use the while ((responseLine = m_dataFromServer.readLine()) != null), the programms cant goes in , because i think m_dataFromServer.readline = null; but i dont understand why